# How to reuse Swift code in other projects?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I wrote a class in Swift. I want to use this code in two separate iOS app projects that I wrote. Both the shared code and the apps are written in Swift. What is the best way of doing that?

I tried to create both a framework and a library in Swift and then add it as a sub-project to my app. In both cases I could not make the app see the module. I tried to add the shared module to "Target Dependencies" and "Link Binary With Libraries" of the main app's target. No luck - the app still can not see the classes of the shared module.

Using Xcode6 Beta6 at the moment.

### Solution

As Konstantin Koval and Heliem pointed out, all I needed is to use `public` in my class and method declarations, in the shared module. Now all works, both if I use workspace and if I add the module as a subproject.

### Update

I just found an excellent easy solution for reusing code between projects in Swift. It is called Carthage (https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). This is not a plug as I am not affiliated with it in any way, I just really like it. It works in iOS 8+.

Comment: I would use [CocoaPods](http://cocoapods.org/), it works well as a dependency manager even if the code is just for you. It will create a workspace with your project and a pod project which could have any number of dependencies. It essentially works the same as adding a framework or library except it will work, even in Swift.

Comment: @tfrank377, is it possible to use CocoaPods to share MY OWN code with MY OWN apps. Or do I need to publish a cocoapods module for that? All the code I write here is private.

Comment: Absolutely, I would be disappointed if it didn't. I'm no CocoaPods expert, but I know we use it at my work for internal reusable components. This [link](https://coderwall.com/p/7ucsva) looked very helpful.

Comment: you can't currently use cocoapods with Swift.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I create an importable module in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24027125/how-do-i-create-an-importable-module-in-swift)

Comment: Are you declaring the classes and methods in the shared module with the `public` keyword?

Comment: Have a look at Alamofire's installation, might be the way to do it for now until CocoaPods works with swift. https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: @Evgeny, if I were you, I would use GIT repositories as submodules or subtrees via https://bitbucket.org or https://github.com. that works a bit more flexible than CocoaPods does in business environment.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

1. Create a new project (iOS Cocoa Touch Framework)  for your reusable code
2. Move your classes to that Framework project
3. Mark your methods and classes, that should be visible to others as `public`
4. Create Workspace.
   You can create a workspace on step 1. When you create new Framework project, Xcode will ask you if you want to create new workspace and add that project to workspace. This is the best approach
5. Add both your project and Framework to the workspace
6. Select you project target -> General tab. Add Framework and Libraries (add your library here)
7. When you want to use code from your Library in swift file, import it using `import 'LibTargetName'`

Comment: Great step by step guide. Would you mind also adding how to import the component in interface builder?

Comment: Searched everywhere and after trying many step by step tutorials (with screenshots) that does NOT work, finally I got it working following the steps here. I just wanted to point out that in no.7, I only got it to work using import TargetName instead of LibTargetName, not sure whether it's because my Xcode version but hope this helps someone!

Comment: Support for "iOS Cocoa Touch Framework" must be a relatively recent feature in Xcode, right?

Comment: This works for me when I compile from the workspace, but I can no longer compile the project by itself.  Is this the reality of the situation?

Comment: Does that still work? With Xcode 7.1 whenever I drop the xcodeproj into the workspace it doesn't 'expand' the project. All I got is a single xcodeproject with not libraries to link at all.

Comment: You mention “Mark your methods and classes, that should be visible to others as public”. Do I need to mark my `init` methods are `public` as well?

Comment: @MartinBean Yes you need. `public init() ...` Also the struct in swift generates Memberwise init methods that are `internal`. so if you want that init to be visible, you need to make it yourself and mark as public.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Is there a way to avoid recompiling the framework before using it in another project?

Comment: The steps are not clear. I am not understanding what needs to be done. Can you please post step by step screenshots? @KostiantynKoval

Answer (score 3):

You can take a more programatic approach by using **SWM** (Swift Modules): https://github.com/jankuca/swm

It is very similar to *npm* (node.js package manager) or *bower* (client-side module manager); you declare your dependencies in a `swiftmodule.json` file like below. It does not have a central module registry like the two mentioned JS solutions, it only accepts git URLs.

```
{
  "name": "ProjectName",
  "dependencies": {
    "Dependency": "git://github.com/…/….git"
  }
}
```

…run `swm install` and have the `Dependency` module (compiled into a `*.swiftmodule` binary) ready for import in the `.modules/` directory.

```
import Dependency
```

And if you prefer to skip Xcode for app development, you can also build your whole app using `swm build` (more info in the project's readme).

The project is still in early stages but it makes itself useful a lot for me at least. It provides the most clean (and clear) way of creating importable modules.

Comment: This is an excellent pragmatic approach; thank you for creating it!

Comment: For future visitors: Apple is pushing the [Swift package manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/). It does not currently integrate with Xcode, but I have to imagine that's in the works.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a video which is very straightforward: http://eonil-observatory.tumblr.com/post/117205738262/a-proper-way-to-add-a-subproject-to-another-xcode

The video is for OS X instead of iOS. But you will get it and figure out the process for iOS.

Let's assume that `AppA` needs to reused code from `SharedProject`.

The following process works for me in Xcode 7 Beta:

1. Create `SharedProject`. Project type must be `Framework` instead of `Application`. You write common code in this project and mark the code as `public`.
2. Open `AppA` in Xcode, open the folder which contains `SharedProject` in Finder. Drag the .xcodeproj file of `SharedProject` from Finder and drop it into the root folder of `AppA` in Xcode Project Navigator.
3. `AppA` --> `Build Phases` --> `Link Binary with Libraries`. Add `SharedProject`.
4. `import SharedProject` and reuse code from `SharedProject`!

**Edit:**

Nowadays I suggest you use [Carthage](https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage). It's better than the home made solution above.

Comment: @jose920405, such as `public class SomePublicClass {}` and `public var somePublicVariable = 0`. But  nowadays I suggest you use Carthage. Please read my updates.

Comment: This helped me. Thanks