# IOS: One 'Cocoa Touch Framework' Library for both Simulator and Real-Device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

I am working with XCODE 6 and SWIFT 1.2 in my iphone application at the moment and loooking a way to share the common codes between projects.

Therefore thought of creating a '**Cocoa Touch Framework**' as explains in following tutorials that contains the codes I want to re-use among projects.

1). [How to reuse Swift code in other projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518077/how-to-reuse-swift-code-in-other-projects)

2). http://locomoviles.com/ios-tutorials/create-ios-cocoa-touch-framework-using-xcode/

3). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86cPaa3FrRg

All ok and I can use the shared codes that contains in the Library project successfully.

**So my problem is**, this is really annoying I have to integrate framwork that contains in `'Debug-iphonesimulator'` folder when testing with **simulator** and again the library that contains in `'Debug-iphoneos'` when testing with a **real device**...

I see Three folders as follows (Built libraries)

[image]

Just generated the release library (the content in 'Release-iphoneos' folder) thinking that this may work in both deice and simulator. But again this works only with real-devices, and not with simulator.

**Question 1).** Can't I generate one library that can build and use in both 'simulator' and on a 'real device'?

**Question 2).** Is there any other way I can link (reference) to Framework Project directly rather than integrating a build library? So Project reference to external Framwork and use resources in there (No library integration... Referencing to project like eclipse android libraries and projects)

Comment: There's maybe a solution for you: http://insert.io/framework-ios8-xcode6/