# Import with Swift on command line

Tags: swift

I want to run a simple swift program on the command line.

I have the following files:

~/calcs/demo.swift  (is executable)

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift

import Foundation
import calcs

println(aString())
```

~/calcs/stringFunctions.swift

```
import Foundation

public func aString() -> String {
    return "1234";
}
```

If I invoke it `$ ./calcs/demo.swift`  it errors with `./calcs/demo.swift:4:8: error: no such module 'calcs'`

If I replace it with `import stringFunctions` it similarly errors.  Or if I comment out `import calcs` then it errors with `use of unresolved identifier 'aString'`.

If I set `FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS` to the parent directory `~/calcs` or `~` it does not successfully find the module either.

```
$ xcrun swift --version
Swift version 1.1 (swift-600.0.57.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0
```

Comment: Is `calcs` an actual framework, or is it directory?

Comment: It's just a directory @dmdm I'm not sure you make it into a framework yet.

Comment: `import` is for modules, not files.

Comment: I think there is an answer here for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089861/how-to-import-modules-without-an-xcode-project-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

As @dmdm stated the correct answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30768381/539490) and was to rename `demo.swift` to `main.swift` and run:

```
$ swiftc ~/calcs/stringFunctions.swift ~/calcs/main.swift
$ ~/calcs/main.swift
1234
```